# Can I ask about optimising WAMP software for certain hardware?

Tags: discussion

I'm building a new PC for myself that I can run a small WAMP website on. It will run on windows 8 with an SSD drive as the boot drive and a hard drive for bulk storage. I would like to ask:

- What optimisations could be made to fine tune the balance between:

  1. taking advantage of the fast random access times of an SSD for quickly serving web pages
  2. avoiding shortening the life of the SSD from excessive write cycles

Would this be an appropriate topic for SE's superuser? If not, is there another SE site I could ask it on? (And which one?)

Edit:

In a way it fits into the accepted topics:

- computer hardware
- computer software
- personal and home computer networking

But at the same time it is borderline with the unaccepted topics:

- programming and software development
- issues specific to corporate IT support and networks

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In theory you could ask a question like that. In practise, you should already have the system set up and should have tried different approaches yourself.

Overall though, it's not a great question because it sounds like you're looking for some magic solution that doesn't exist. If you want fast access times, use the SSD. Case closed.

You should ask yourself what you actually need though. Set up your site and measure your performance, then see if you need to improve it. With a stack that involves PHP, there are definitely other optimizations that could be applied before even looking into storage (depending on what your site actually *does*).

Comment: Thanks, that's a good idea. My main thought was perhaps keeping as much as possible in RAM, keeping as many things that are just read as possible on the SSD, and the rest on the HDD. I don't expect a magical solution, but more exploring the options of how granular the arrangements can be as to what goes in RAM vs SSD vs HDD. But I will set it up first and see how it goes. Thanks again